Is there a way to filter out negative Interval values?
Currently I have a interval column after subtracting two timestamp without time zone columns
SELECT started_at - ended_at AS ride_length
FROM [dbo]

However,  I am getting negative values for the intervals and I want to filter them out.
I tried:
SELECT *
FROM [dbo]
WHERE ride_length < 0

and it returns this error
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. 

But I cannot change the datatype of the column.

Compare with an interval:
SELECT ended_at - started_at AS ride_length
FROM [dbo]
WHERE ended_at - started_at < INTERVAL '0 SECOND'

Note also the reversal of the columns: duration is end minus start.
